# install databricks inside azure self-hosted pool in windows

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

The main idea is installed databricks, so I use the following script:

```
     - task: CmdLine@2
       displayName: "Install databricks cli"
       inputs:
         script: |
           pip install databricks-cli --user    
           pip install databricks
         workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)/${{ parameters.IrropsMLService }}

     - script: |
         databricks --version
```

But I faced with problem:
*'databricks' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*
Could you help me to resole the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First remove databricks connect and also to uninstall any pyspark installation.
And then follow the installation guide.

1. Uninstall PySpark. This is required because the databricks-connect package conflicts with PySpark.

   ```
   pip uninstall pyspark
   ```
2. Install the Databricks Connect client.

`pip install -U "databricks-connect==7.3.*"`  # or `X.Y.*` to match your cluster version.

Note - Always specify databricks-connect==X.Y.* instead of databricks-connect=X.Y, to make sure that the newest package is installed.

For more information follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect)